# Program to calculate the distance between two points is producing strange output.

Tags: c

This is a simple script to try to calculate the distance between two points. It compiles fine, and then it outputs answer like 2340000456 for the points (1,2) (3,4). I cannot figure out where I went wrong here.

```
/*******************************
  * squarecalc finds the distance between two points *
  * Purpose: allow the user to input two points and find the distance between them per a cartesian plane *
  * References: "Practical C Programming" *
*******************************/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

char line1[25]; // Point 1 in type char, format "x1, y1"
char line2[25]; // Point 2 in type char, format "x2, y2"
char point1[25];
char point2[25];
double x1; 
double why1;
double x2;
double why2;
char *search = ", "; // Value on which to 'split' when using strtok on points
double horizontal; // length of horizontal side of triangle
double verticle; // length of verticle side of trianglle
double hypotenuse; // lenght of hypotenuse of triangle


int main()
{
  /* --------------------Recieve and Format Input--------------------- */
  /* Prompts user to input a point, then assigns coordinates from point to x1 and y1 */
  printf("Enter first point [e.g. 1, 2]: "); // Prompt user for first point
  fgets(line1, sizeof(line1), stdin); // Read from standard input
  /* Convert point input to integers, format necessary for calculations */ 
  sscanf(strtok(line1, search), "%lf", &x1); // Assign x coordinate to constant variable x1
  sscanf(strtok(NULL, search), "%lf", &why1); // Assign y coordinate to constant variable y1
  /* strtok: used to strip x and y coordinates from point1-char (e.x. to get 'x1' from 'x1, y1') */
  /* sscanf: used to convert the value returned from strtok to an integer */ 

  /* prompts user to input a point, then assigns coordinates from point to  x2 and y2 */
  printf("Enter second point: "); // prompt user for second point
  fgets(line2, sizeof(line2), stdin);
  sscanf(strtok(line2, search), "%lf", &x2);
  sscanf(strtok(NULL, search), "%lf", &why2);

  /* ---------------------Calculate Distance--------------------------- */

  horizontal = x1-x2;
  verticle = why1-why2;
  hypotenuse = sqrt(pow(abs(horizontal),2)+pow(abs(verticle),2));

  /* ---------------------Print/Output Results------------------------- */
  printf("The distance between point one (P1) and point two (P2) is %lf.\n", hypotenuse);

}
```

Comment: The axis perpendicular to the X-axis is usually referred to as `y`, not `why`.

Comment: I can't reproduce the exact problem you describe -- "2340000456 for the points (1,2) (3,4)".  But I am getting wrong results for fractional values, i.e. the distance from (1,1) to (1.1,1.1) is being printed as zero, due to the abs/fabs problem.

Comment: @Jashaszun Y is that? :-)

Comment: Just a note, traditionally distance is computed from `y2-y1` and `x2-x1`. It is only relevant to vector direction. Your answer regarding magnitude with be the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `fabs()` (FP math) rather than `abs()` (integer math).

Suspect OP's interesting answer of `2340000456` occurred because unneeded `abs()` was not properly prototype - hence Undefined Behavior (UB).

```
// hypotenuse = sqrt(pow(abs(horizontal),2)+pow(abs(verticle),2));
hypotenuse = sqrt(pow(fabs(horizontal),2)+pow(fabs(verticle),2));
```

---

Anytime there is user input and unexpected results, always a good idea to check results:

```
if (fgets(line2, sizeof(line2), stdin) != NULL) Handle_EOF();
char *p = strtok(line1, search);
if (p == NULL) Handle_TokenFailure();
if (sscanf(p, "%lf", &x1) != 1) Handle_ScanFailure();
```

No need to take absolute value when squaring.

```
hypotenuse = sqrt(pow(horizontal,2) + pow(verticle,2));
```

No need to write own sqrt(sum of squares).

```
hypotenuse = hypot(horizontal, verticle);
```

Minor: spelling:

"verticle" --"vertical"
"Recieve" --> "Receive"
"trianglle" --> "triangle"
"lenght" --> "length"

Comment: If one believes "oh surely those typos are harmless": [they may persist all the way into the documentation](http://www.indd-skript.de/extendscriptAPI/indesign10/index.html#Screeening.html), and then it's too late to fix them.

Comment: thanks yea I am dislexic, so spelling is a bit of a problem, especially when I am writing my code in nano.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing [`abs`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/abs/) to [`fabs`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/fabs/).  `abs` is [for integers](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Absolute-Value.html) while `fabs` is for doubles.